# Designing a java cat art using ascii

Tags: java

[image]

Can anyone show me how to draw this "cat" face using java. I tried the following but I am not sure how to make this drawing work. I mean I know /n can be used to skip a line and I know to display / you have to do //. But I am having a tough time figuring this out.

```
public class PrintCat { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         System.out.println("//\\_\\//");

         System.out.println("// 0 0 \\  ");

         System.out.println("\\ \n \\~(*)~  ");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried my best but I cant figure it out,  I would do it if I knew how..

Comment: I admit I just started learning java so please do not be harsh people.. please...

Comment: Well to display / you can just use /. To display a \ you need \\ is one thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should print what you're asking for.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("   /\\_/\\   ");
    System.out.println("  / o o \\  ");
    System.out.println(" (   \"   ) ");
    System.out.println("  \\~(*)~/  ");
    System.out.println("   // \\\\   ");
}
```

It's just a matter of adding an extra `\` before each `\` and `"` characters.

I've *drawn* (*ie*, wrote the characters of) the cat first, without any escaping, and only then did I escape the appropriate characters.
As to the spacing, you can easily figure it out writing spaces, provided you're using a monospaced font.

Comment: Thank you most kind sir the computer gods will sing praises in your name.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez Dude, deep.

Answer (score 5):

```
System.out.println(" /\\_/\\");
System.out.println("/ o o \\");
```

will print the ears and eyes for the cat, i don't know why you are doing:
    //, '/' is fine to use, you only need to escape the '\' characters and " character, other than that it should be trial and error to get the spacing correct and face aligned right :)

Comment: How do you get it spaced correctly thorough the indentation confuses me

Comment: Try using simple spaces or `\t` for Tab

Comment: the println() will print whitespaces, id suggest getting each line sorted visually and then play with adding whitespaces to each line to align them :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     System.out.println("       /\\_/\\");
     System.out.println("      / 0 0 \\  ");
     System.out.println("     (   \"   )");
     System.out.println("      \\~(*)~/  ");
     System.out.println("       // \\\\");

}
```